# For loops: Running through column names

Tags: r, regression

I was looking for a shorter way to write this using for loops

ie: i is 1 to 22 and my data will add columns 1 through 22 in the multiple regression:

```
reg <-lm(log(y)~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+z1+z+z3+z4+z5+z6+z7+z8+z9+z10+z11+z12, data)
```

To clarify, x1 and x2 and x3 are all column names - they are x two (not x squared), I am trying to do a multiple regression with the last 22 columns in my data set

Someone suggested to do this:

```
reg1 <- lm(log(data$y)~terms( as.formula( 
  paste(" ~ (", paste0("X", 29:ncol(data) , collapse="+"), ")")
)         
))
```

But

1. It doesn't work
2. I don't think it is doing multiple regression (xone + xtwo+ xthree), rather it assigned the binary value 1 to each variable x1, x2, x3... and added them, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I know that a for-loop was requested but it would have been a clumsy strategy, so here's a possible correct strategy:

```
formchr <- paste(  
            paste( "log(y)" , paste0( "x", 1:10, collapse="+"), sep="~"),  
                   # the LHS and first 10 terms
                                paste0( "z", 1:12, collapse="+"), #next 12 terms
                   sep="+")   # put both parts together
reg1 <- lm( as.formula(formchr), data=data)
```

The full character-version of the formula should be passed to the `as.formula` function and the `paste` and `paste0` functions are fully vectorized, so no loop is needed.

If the first 22 columns were the desired target for the RHS terms, you could have pasted together `names(data)[1:22]` or `...[29:50]` if those were hte locations, and htis would be substituted for the RHS terms in the second `paste` above, dropping the third `paste`.

The only reason I used `data` as the name of an object is that it was implied by the question. It is a very confusing practice to use that name. `data` is an R function and objects should have specific names that do not overlap with function names. The other very commonly abused name in this regard is `df`, which is the density function for the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You could first subset your data into a data.frame which contains only the columns of interest. Then, you can run a linear model using the `.` formula syntax to select all columns other than the y variable.

Example using 1000 rows and 50 cols of data

```
N <- 1000
P <- 50
data <- as.data.frame(rep(data.frame(rnorm(N)), P))
```

Assign your y data to y.

```
y <- as.data.frame(rep(data.frame(rnorm(N)), 1))
```

Create a new data.frame containing y and the last 22 columns.

```
   model_data <- cbind(y, data[ ,29:50])
   colnames(model_data) <- c("y", paste0("x", 1:10), paste0("z",1:12))
```

The following should do the trick. The `.` formula syntax will select all columns other than the y column.

```
 reg <-lm(log(y) ~ ., data = model_data)
```

Comment: Maybe, but given the question probably not. It will pull in ALL columns other than `y` regardless if they precede or follow `y`.

Comment: Now your answer is ignoring the fact that some of the columns were named `xNN` and some were named `zNN` (and clearly not with NN starting at 28.)